# How does == (equals) work under the hood in Ruby 1.8?

Tags: ruby, string

The following describes what seems to be a bug in Ruby 1.8 (and REE) but has been fixed in 1.9.

I'd like to know:

1. Why calling `==` on `String` or `Fixnum` triggers calling `==` on `other` object at all?
2. Why calling `==` on `String` works differently depending on the `other` object class?

Now the code:

```
class A
  def ==(other)
    puts "In A: calling == against #{other}"
    super
  end
end

class E < Exception
  def ==(other)
    puts "In E: calling == against #{other}"
    super
  end
end
```

#### Example 1

```
"foo" == A.new
=> false
```

Nothing interesting here, move along.

#### Example 2

```
"foo" == E.new
In E: calling == against foo
=> false
```

Calling `==` on `String` triggers `==` on `other` object of `Exception` class.

#### Example 3

```
42 == A.new
In A: calling == against 42
=> false
```

Calling `==` on `Fixnum` triggers `==` on `other` object.

#### Example 4

```
42 == E.new
In E: calling == against 42
=> false
```

Calling `==` on `String` triggers `==` on `other` object of `Exception` class.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @mbratch the questions are on top of the page.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ruby 1.8 is discontinued but not the projects that use it. Besides I'm simply curious about how it works internally.

Comment: @MichałSzajbe: yes, I shouldn't have posted that. Healthy curiosity is our bread. :) Kudos to Chris, who actually does know how it works.

Comment: @Michal - my apologies. Senior moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is only the case for certain types - Fixnums, in this case. I'm not able to replicate your Example #2 (Edit: I did, see the bottom), but Examples 3 and 4 replicate easily enough.

So, looking at numeric.c, we see that Ruby calls `equal?` on `y` (the second parameter), not `x`.

```
static VALUE
num_equal(x, y)
    VALUE x, y;
{
    if (x == y) return Qtrue;
    return rb_funcall(y, id_eq, 1, x);
}
```

Take a look at this example:

```
1.8.7 :001 > class Foo
1.8.7 :002?>   def ==(other)
1.8.7 :003?>     puts "In foo"
1.8.7 :004?>     super
1.8.7 :005?>     end
1.8.7 :006?>   end
 => nil
1.8.7 :007 > 42 == Foo.new
In foo
 => false
1.8.7 :008 > Foo.new == 42
In foo
 => false
1.8.7 :009 > Foo.new == Foo.new
In foo
 => false
1.8.7 :010 > "" == Foo.new
 => false
```

In #7, we compare `42` (x) with `Foo.new` (y). This invokes `y.==(x)`, which is going to call `Foo#==`.

In #8, we reverse it; there's nothing interesting here, we just call `Foo#==` and it behaves as expected.

However, in #9, comparing two instances of `Foo` results in only one call to `Foo#==`. `==` isn't called on the argument, only on the receiver.

#10 doesn't invoke `Foo#==` at all.

The swapped comparison is a quirk of Ruby's numeric types' implementation of `==`, not a specific property of Ruby's equality operators themselves.

Edit: Strings have the same thing going on.

```
static VALUE
rb_str_equal(str1, str2)
    VALUE str1, str2;
{
    if (str1 == str2) return Qtrue;
    if (TYPE(str2) != T_STRING) {
      if (!rb_respond_to(str2, rb_intern("to_str"))) {
        return Qfalse;
      }
      return rb_equal(str2, str1);
    }
    if (RSTRING(str1)->len == RSTRING(str2)->len &&
      rb_str_cmp(str1, str2) == 0) {
      return Qtrue;
    }
    return Qfalse;
}
```

It invokes `rb_equal` with the second parameter first. The reason that it doesn't call `Foo#==` is that `Foo` in my example doesn't implement `#to_str`, so it just returns false. `Exception`, however, implements `#to_str`, so a subclass of it gets passed to the `rb_equal` test in your example.

Comment: Thanks, I was going through the C code myself but misinterpreted `rb_equal` function, namely the `id_eq` argument of its `rb_funcall` invocation. Still not sure what `id_eq` is in that context.

Comment: Check object.c - it's basically just the C reference to the `Object#eql?` Ruby function.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is an object-oriented language. In an object-oriented language, you send messages to objects and those objects then respond to those messages however they see fit.

This means that the receiver of the message, and *only* the receiver(!) is in *total* control of what a message means.

With some operators, however, there are certain expectations of symmetry: for example, `a == b` is expected to be the same as `b == a`. But in an OO language that is *impossible*! Either `a` or `b` *must* be the receiver of the message, so in one case `a` gets to decide whether `a` and `b` are equal and in the other case `b` gets to decide. They might decide differently, and then the expectation of symmetry would be broken.

So, in some classes equality is actually implemented something like this:

> If I know who you are, *I* decide whether we are equal. But if I don't know who you are, I will let *you* decide, because maybe *you* know who *I* am!

Here's an example: if you write your own `Numeric` class (say, a `Quaternion` class), then the system builtin `Fixnum` class doesn't know anything about `Quaternion`s. So, when you ask the `Fixnum` `0` whether it is equal to the `Quaternion` `(0, 0, 0, 0)`, it will responds `false`, even though that's *wrong*.

So, instead the `Fixnum` will first check: do I know how to compare myself to a `Quaternion`? No, I don't, but maybe a `Quaternion` knows how to compare itself to a `Fixnum`! After all, the `Quaternion` class didn't exist when the `Fixnum` class was written, so the `Fixnum` class *cannot* know about `Quaternion`s. But when the `Quaternion` class was written, maybe the author was so thoughtful to make it possible to compare `Quaternion`s with `Fixnum`s.

*That's* why `Fixnum#==` reverses the arguments and tries again.

With `String`, it's the same but somewhat more complicated. In Ruby, *classes* aren't *types* and *subtyping* and *subclassing* are different. Ruby itself doesn't have a concept of *type* at all! The *type* of an object is its *protocol*, i.e. the messages it understands and how it responds to them. But that concept is not recorded in Ruby (unlike Objective-C, for example, which *does* have an explicit notion of *protocol*).

There, however, some cases, where you *want* to break OO encapsulation, and *know* the specific type and even more: the specific *representation* of the type. (Note: this violates OO, but it is sometimes necessary for performance.)

In cases, where Ruby needs an object to be of a *specific* class instead of just responding to a specific protocol, you would lose a lot of flexibility. You *have* to use, say, a `String`, even though you would much rather use a `Rope` instead. In order to give you back some flexibility, Ruby allows you to pass in something which is not exactly a `String` but which is equivalent to one and can be converted to one with a `to_str` method. So, unlike other languages, where `A IS-A String` is represented by `A` being a subclass of `String`, in Ruby, the relationship `A IS-A String` is represented by `A` having a `to_str` method.

That's what you are seeing above. If the argument to `String#==` isn't a `String`, then `String#==` doesn't know what to do with it. But if it is "string-like", i.e. it implements `to_str`, then maybe *it* does know how to compare itself to a `String`?

Note that equality is *very* hard to get right. People cannot even agree on what it means in a purely functional language, and that's the *easy* case! In Ruby, there are two additional complications: mutable state and OO. Mutable state means that two objects that were equal a moment ago may not be equal anymore a couple of moments later. Or should they be? Or shouldn't they be? And OO means that equality *cannot* be symmetric.

That's why the implementations of `==` for various core and stdlib classes are constantly improved. That's also why you may see weird behavior now and again. Sometimes it may just be an artifact of trying to get equality right, and sometimes it might just simply be a bug.

By the way: for the *arithmetic* operators, subclasses of `Numeric` actually have a more formal double-dispatch protocol using the `coerce` method. If a `Numeric` object doesn't know what to do with another `Numeric`, it will ask that other object to `coerce` the two objects to a type that *does* know that. For example, if you try to add a `Quaternion` to a `Fixnum`, the `Fixnum` won't know what to do:

```
2 + Quaternion.new(1, 0, 0, 0)
```

The `+` method of `Fixnum` will then call:

```
a, b = other.coerce(self)
```

IOW: it will call `Quaternion#coerce` with the equivalent of

```
Quaternion.new(1, 0, 0, 0).coerce(2)
```

to which `Quaternion` will respond with an `Array` of `[Quaternion.new(2, 0, 0, 0), Quaternion.new(1, 0, 0, 0)]`

Then, `Fixnum#+` will try again by simply calling

```
a + b
```

Which will now work because `a` is a `Quaternion` also and knows how to add two `Quaternion`s.

A very common implementation of `coerce` is simply to swap the arguments, i.e.

```
def coerce(other)
  return other, self
end
```

That's equivalent to the behavior you are seeing with `Fixnum#==`.

Again: this kind of dispatch is hard to get right, and there are improvements being made to the `coerce` protocol.

Comment: Great explanation, I didn't think about from this perspective. This approach may cause problems when `other` object redefines `==` method and makes assumptions about its `other` object. This is why I stumbled  on this problem. Now I see how `coerce` protocol helps in dealing with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has four levels of object equivalence:

1. `#equal?` – same object
2. `#eql?` – highest level of equivalence below same object
3. `#==` – "standard" equality
4. `#===`, `#=~`, `#hash`, etc. – loose equivalence, "same group" equivalence

Mindful programmer equips each of her classes with all of these methods except `#equal?`, which should never be overriden. Going back to the subject of your question, many built-in Ruby objects have their share of idiosyncrasies in the implementation of these methods. Ruby core team constantly works to improve them, so you should make your way from 1.8 to 2.0, which fixes a number of 1.8 problems. One more thing to mention with `#==` method, is that for the classes that represent elements of ordered sets, you do not implement `#==` directly, but instead you provide `#<=>` three-way comparison method, and include `Comparable` module, which gives you for free methods such as `#==`, `#<`, `#>`, `#sort`, etc. Yet one more thing to mention with all of these operators and operator-like methods, be mindful of the existence of `#coerce` method, which is currently undergoing improvements in Ruby 2.0.